# How to test if a base64 string is a valid image in PHP?

Tags: php, image, base64

How to test if a base64 string is a valid image in PHP?

I tried the following code:

```
function convertAndSaveLogo($data, $id){
        if(isset($data->base64_image) && $data->base64_image){
            $imageData = base64_decode($data->base64_image);
            if($imageData){
                $source = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);
                if($source){
                    imagepng($source, getcwd()."../dir/image/".$id.".png", 5);
                    imagedestroy($source);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Is the data a data uri or just a base64 encoded image?

Comment: @Musa The base64 string is a user supplied data, I need to know if it is a valid encoded image

Comment: So what about your function that doesn't work?

Comment: @Musa If the base64 string is a invalid encoded image the function imagecreatefromstring will throw an error

Comment: So it throws an error when it shouldn't?

Comment: @Musa Yes. Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if(base64_encode(base64_decode($img, true)) === $img)
   echo 'is a Base64-encoded string' ;
```

Comment: Exact duplicate advice as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10797086/2943403

Answer (score 1):

Look into two things

1. if $data->base64_image doesn't contain something like:
   'data:image/jpeg;base64,', in my case replacing it to nothing does the job:

   ```
   //in my case base64 data resides in: \Input::all()['img_data']
   $base64img = str_replace(
        'data:image/jpeg;base64,', 
        '', 
        \Input::all()['img_data']
   );

   $data = base64_decode($base64img);
   ```
2. if you're saving that you can as well check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919460/how-do-detect-if-the-selected-image-for-upload-is-a-valid-image/9919519) :

   ```
   // if it returns FALSE then the uploaded file
   // isn't a valid image
   getimagesize($created_file);
   ```

Comment: I don't want to save the file if the base64 is not a valid encoded image. So I can not use getimagesize.